# fb:like_box failed to resize in 45s

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-likebox

Is there any working solutions to prevent Facebook Like Box to not breaking his container or something ? Have set the **async** to TRUE but still gets out. As I can see on stackoverflow there are issues only for **fb:login_button**, however I receive the same warning to console:

```
fb:like_box failed to resize in 45s
```

To sum up, here is my code, perhaps I am missing something.

HTML Tag

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

FB Initialization

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({
                    appId: <?php echo $this->config['facebook']['appId']; ?>,
                    status: true,
                    cookie: true,
                    xfbml: true
                });

                /* All the events registered */
                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) {
                    // do something with response
                    alert("login success");
                });
                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function (response) {
                    // do something with response
                    alert("logout success");
                });

                FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                    if (response.session) {
                        // logged in and connected user, someone you know
                        alert("login success");
                    }
                });
            };
            (function () {
                var e = document.createElement('script');
                e.type = 'text/javascript';
                e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
                e.async = true;
                document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
            } ());
        </script>
```

FB Like Box

```
<div class="facebook-plugin">
        <div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/****" data-width="346" data-show-faces="true" data-header="true" data-stream="false" data-show-border="true"></div>
    </div>
```

This is it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you testing this on localhost?  I had an identical problem that resolved itself when I went live.

Comment: Yes, projects are tested on local before going live. But the main issue is that theere are times when Facebook LikeBox forget to resize or to fit back in his container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accordingly to new Facebook API upgrade, they give up to Like Box, therefore this is no longer an issue.

> With the release of Graph API v2.3, the **Like Box plugin** is deprecated. Please use the new **Page Plugin** instead. The ***Page Plugin*** allows you to embed a simple feed of content from a Page into your websites.
>
> If you do not manually upgrade to the Page Plugin, your Like Box plugin implementation will automatically fall back to the Page Plugin by *June 23rd 2015*.

Page Plugin link is https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin